# FCM Push Notifications implementation for Cordova App

Tags: cordova, firebase-cloud-messaging

Are there any relevant UpToDate documentation available for implementing push notifications using Firebase FCM for Cordova App.

I tried implementing it by watching some youtube videos but all of them are out of date and doesn't work now.

Comment: Have you tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/@havesource/cordova-plugin-push